# Wrong indexpath with two custom UITableViewCell in table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two custom cells in my table view that I can display correctly. `MyCustomCellB` has a button and when the user taps this button I call a segue programatically, that also works, but imports wrong variables. It takes different data which "belongs" to a `MyCustomCellA` typed cell. But, if I first select the cell and then tap the button it works fine, somehow after the selection it gets the right data.

Is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is incorrect?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([object[@"num"] isEqualToString:@"one"]) {

        MyCustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

         //... cell display
        cell.acceptLabel.tag = indexPath.row;
        [cell.acceptLabel addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapBttn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        return cell;

    } else {

        MyCustomTableViewCellB *cellMessage = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        //... cell display

        return cellMessage;

    }

}

- (void)didTapBttn:(id)sender {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"info" sender:self];

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"info"]) {
        if ([[segue destinationViewController] isKindOfClass:[DViewController class]]) {

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

            DViewController *datap = [segue destinationViewController];

            PFObject *passObj = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            datap.infoName = passObj[@"infoName"];
            datap.infoId = passObj[@"id"];

        }

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"desc"]) {
        if ([[segue destinationViewController] isKindOfClass:[DViewController class]]) {

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

            DViewController *datap = [segue destinationViewController];

            PFObject *passObj = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            datap.infoN = passObj[@"descName"];
            datap.infoId = passObj[@"descId"];

        }
    }
```

Comment: what is object dictionary? i.e. the one: [object[@"num"]

Comment: @Alex It's a custom object, it contains some string properties.

Comment: Are you expecting its value to change during your table reload so that you can instantiate different table view cell types? I feel like this is a horrible code design decision. What is the purpose of this `object[@"num"]` value?

Comment: What do you mean with "imports wrong variables"? Which variables and how do you pass them? In prepareForSeque?

Comment: @IanMacDonald how would you do it?

Comment: You need to show how you're passing the data since that's where your problem is. If you are implementing didSelectRowAtIndexPath and/or prepareForSegue, show them.

Comment: @rdelmar question updated with prepareForSegue

Comment: When you click on a button, there is no selectedRow -- the cell is not selected.

Comment: @rdelmar So I need to select the cell programmatically somehow in the  didTapBttn: before I call the segue?

Answer (score 1):

You can extend your didTappBttn with some data (i.e. NSDictionary) so you have to be sure it always contains desired data.Also tag in your code is not relevant if you don't interpret it. Maybe data should be row at indexpath tag.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since you don't do anything in your button method other than call performSegue, you should make the segue directly from the button instead of the controller, and delete the button's action method. Then in prepareForSegue:sender:, the sender argument will be the button. You need to get the indexPath of the cell that the button was contained in.  There are multiple ways to do that. One way is to use the table view method indexPathForRowAtPoint:, and pass the button's origin (after converting to the table view's coordinate system) as the point.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UIButton *)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"info"]) {
        if ([[segue destinationViewController] isKindOfClass:[DViewController class]]) {
            CGPoint p = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];

            DViewController *datap = [segue destinationViewController];

            PFObject *passObj = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            datap.infoName = passObj[@"infoName"];
            datap.infoId = passObj[@"id"];

        }

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"desc"]) {
        if ([[segue destinationViewController] isKindOfClass:[DViewController class]]) {

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

            DViewController *datap = [segue destinationViewController];

            PFObject *passObj = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            datap.infoN = passObj[@"descName"];
            datap.infoId = passObj[@"descId"];

        }
    }
```

I don't know whether you need to make the same change for the "desc" segue since I don't know how that one is being triggered.