# prepareForSegue passes value for Index 0...ALWAYS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

I have an array of items displayed in a `TableViewController`. They display properly in the TVC. The code below segues, but it only segues to `indexPath 0` of my array of `MKMapItem`s, not the item from the cell that was clicked.

Any thoughts on where my mistake is?

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *mapItems;
```

Each cell has a "Add POI" `UIButton` which that triggers a segue created with Interface Builder called "addPOISegue".

[image: Here's the Cell]

[image: Here's the Segue Identifier]

Here's the IBAction for the "Add POI" button:

```
- (IBAction)addPOIButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Add POI button clicked");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addPOISegue" sender:sender];
}
```

Here's the `prepareForSegue

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UIButton*)sender {

//    NSLog(@"The sender is %@", sender);
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"addPOISegue"]) {
        AddPOIViewController *destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:sender.center];
        NSLog(@"NSIndexPath *indexPath's index is %@", indexPath);
        MKMapItem *item = _mapItems[indexPath.row];
//        NSLog(@"ResultsTVC item is %@", item);
        destinationVC.item = item;
    }

}
```

The indexPath keeps getting set to 0. I suspect this is because I've got a button triggering the segue within the cell, but I'm stumped as to how to resolve this.

Comment: Did you make the segue directly from the button? If so, you shouldn't be calling performSegue.

Comment: How would I set the property for the `destinationViewController`? I tried fiddling with that, but I couldn't get the property on it to set.

Comment: You do that in prepareForSegue, like you already are. See my answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818617/wrong-indexpath-with-two-custom-uitableviewcell-in-table-view/28819550#28819550) for how to get the indexPath

Comment: I'm stumped as to why my `segue` isn't passing the value. My array in `VC1` is an array of `MKMapItems`.  I'm trying to pick the row displaying info from `VC1` and send that value to `AddPOIViewController`. This is 101 stuff. It's extremely frustrating not to figure something so simple out.

Comment: Did you look at the link I provided? When you click on a button, the cell is not selected, so indexPathForSelectedRow will be nil. You need to use indexPathForRowAtPoint: and pass the button's center to the point parameter (the sender will be the button in prepareForSegue:sender).

Comment: I tried that, but I don't have a `CGPoint`. How would I create or retrieve the value? I created the button via Interface Builder. `sender.center` doesn't do it.

Comment: Just like I showed in my link. Change the sender argument in prepareForSegue:Sender: to "(UIButton *) sender" instead if "id", and then you pass sender.center as the point argument.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this resolved with snippets in comments. Thank you for your help on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72694/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-adrian-b).

Comment: I added the correct code to our chat, and corrected the code in my link as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delete the button's action method, and connect the segue directly from the button to the next controller. In prepareForSegue, you can pass the button's origin, after converting it to the table view's coordinate system to the indexPathForRowAtPoint: method to get the indexPath of the cell that button is contained in,

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UIButton*)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"addPOISegue"]) {
        AddPOIViewController *destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        CGPoint p = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
        NSLog(@"NSIndexPath *indexPath's index is %@", indexPath);
        MKMapItem *item = _mapItems[indexPath.row];
//        NSLog(@"ResultsTVC item is %@", item);
        destinationVC.item = item;
    }

}
```

Comment: Many thanks! I really appreciate your over the top assistance on this basic problem.

Answer (score 0):

@rdelmar figured it out. I needed a `CGPoint` due to the `UIButton` contained in my cell and referenced within my `prepareForSegue` method.

This code got it working:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UIButton*)sender {

//    NSLog(@"The sender is %@", sender);
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"addPOISegue"]) {
        AddPOIViewController *destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController;

        CGPoint point = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
        NSLog(@"NSIndexPath *indexPath's index is %@", indexPath);
        MKMapItem *item = _mapItems[indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"ResultsTVC item is %@", item);
        destinationVC.item = item;
    }

}
```